# DeadObjectException when pressure test

Tags: java, android

Our application receives the client's request through AIDL, then executes a processing flow, and finally returns the processing result to the client. When I performed a stress test on the application, I found that the following exception would be thrown every time the complete process was executed about 400 times.
The crash log is:

```
11-05-06-20-59.583 E CrashHandler.java[101](handleExceptions)[1]Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:652)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3518)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2733)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:623)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:828)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:640)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Client process died, as stated in the exception message.

Comment: But this crash information appears in the server processing flow, not when communicating with the client.

Comment: When the exception says "Caused by: ..." that's a very strong hint from Java that this exception is the result of a deeper problem, and seemingly the death of the remote process is a likely candidate. There are situations where the remote process may die, without any stack trace (e.g. when it is killed by the kernel for out-of-memory).  My approach would be to see if you can get close to the exception and analyze the other process for whether it's close to some OS limit (file handles, memory, ...) at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the analysis of the memory, it was found that the Handler object was repeatedly created when the AIDL command was initiated, and the Handler object was not cleaned up in time, resulting in a memory leak.